# Insertion sort algorithm Permitive Operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

I recently studied about primitive operations in data structures (Java). I was  trying to apply primitive operations on insertion sort algorithm. I found that when a loop comes in the body of another loop, it gives its operation in form of **summation** According to the following slide.
[image]

But i found its another representation that another loop is coming and its not giving its primitive operation in **summation** form like:
 [image]
I am confused about the operation of for loop. Why `for` loop is not having **summation** operation. Can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses summation method to analyze the insertion sort. The second one uses the "frequency count method" to analyze the same algorithm. Both are valid. I recommend to use that methods in the same algorithm (first case).